# Problem with mod_deflate - compressing executable file

Tags: apache, mod-deflate

When trying to download file with.EXE extension in the site, the files are coming as .GZ
Environment
Centos 7 64
Apache 2.4.6

Changing the file in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf I have already tried using each of these forms below, however, to no avail (I restarted apache and deleted the browser cache on each attempt):

1:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.exe$ no-gzip dont-vary
```

2:

```
 <FilesMatch \.exe$>
        SetEnv no-gzip 1
    </FilesMatch>
```

3:

```
SetEnv mod_deflate off
```

4:

```
SetEnv no-gzip off
```

5:
In the file `/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-base.conf` I commented:

```
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
```

6:
I tried to delete the file, but it did not work.

```
/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_deflate.so
```

Comment: By default mod_deflate won't compress the .exe files. You probably have some custom settings that results into that compression. I have mod_deflate enabled on my server and I can download plain .exe files

Comment: It may have been the "AddType" directive that I was using.

Answer (score -1):

I was reviewing httpd.conf and when I removed the addtype directive (AddType application / x-gzip .tgz .rar .zip .exe .dll) the EXE file was no longer compressed.

I had put this because the browser was taking too long to start the download EXE, in addition, RAR file instead of downloading, was being displayed as a binary in the browser.

So I did the following to solve (I do not know if it was the indicated output, but my knowledge is not enough, I'm new in this area):

```html
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml...:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom_xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-httpd-php
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-httpd-fastphp
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-httpd-eruby
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch ^HMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png|zip|bz2|rar|exe|pdf|doc|dll|jpg|sit|mp4|mov|mp3|3gp|webm|rm|avi|ogv)$ no-gzip dont-vary
<FilesMatch \.exe$>
ForceType application/exe
Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch \.rar$>
ForceType application/rar
Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Just define the correct mime types for exe and rar. Using FilesMatch declarations is overkill

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: With `AddType`: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype